# What does mean modulo $2\pi$?

Tags: notation

I was reading a paper and it have a equation inside absolute value with a small $2\pi$ on the right corner , the paper explains
$|\cdot|_{2\pi}$ denotes modulo $2\pi$ .

[image]

Comment: What is the paper?

Comment: For such a question you should give a link to the paper. Otherwise it is difficult to verify the answers.

Comment: It seems that we will never know the paper.

Comment: It is not a standard notation, so the authors may have defined it within the paper to denote everything they like.  If you are not interested in that paper, you can also give to it any meaning you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression inside the vertical bars seems to be calculating an angle. We often want to describe an angle in radians as a value between $0$ and $2\pi$. If the result of that calculation does not end up in that range, add or subtract an appropriate multiple of $2\pi$ to put it there. That's the number meant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \mathbb R$. $$|x|_{2\pi} \text{ means } \{x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb Z\}$$
So, $|\cdot|_{2\pi}$ means the function $$\mathbb R \to \mathcal{P(}\mathbb R), x\mapsto \{x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb Z\}$$
We can be more specific. On $\mathbb R$, we define the relation $\sim$ by $$x\sim y\iff (\exists k\in \mathbb Z:x-y=2k\pi)$$ This is an equivalence relation and we can specify : $|\cdot|_{2\pi}$ means the function $$\mathbb R \to \textbf{T}:=\mathbb R/\sim, x\mapsto \{x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb Z\}$$, ie the canonical projection.

Comment: Are you sure? When I read the question, the first thing I thought is that $|x|_{2\pi}$ is the unique $y$ in $[0,2\pi)$ such that $x \sim y$ (using your notation).

Comment: @azif00 : i'm not sure but I've never come across the feature you're talking about. Does such a function do anything? In any case, the canonical projection is useful.